# Update Mojarra libraries on OpenShift JBoss AS 7

Tags: jboss, openshift-online-2

I'm trying to run my application on OpenShift JBoss AS 7 but I ran into a bug in older versions of Mojarra which are unfortunatelly shipped with the server.

https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2277

On my local JBoss, I was able to modify module.xml files and updated JSF libraries and make it work. OpenShift however does not allow me to do so beacuse only root have access to JBoss configuration files.

Is there any way how to update or ask for update of those libraries?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to find the solution which is creation of new modules in `.openshift` directory in your Git repository.

Just create the same structure as you would in JBoss server in `.openshift/config/modules` and push it. Your modules will be loaded instead of the original ones.